# Create a Corresponding Entity Reference preset programmatically

Tags: 7

I'm using the [CER module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) in Drupal 7. Is there a way to create a preset programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT]

Almost a year later, I found a better way (the entity_import way actually did not work).

CERs are entities. The best way to create one is using `$cer = entity_create('cer', array('bundle' => 'cer'));`   adding appropriate values to the fields of the created entity, and saving it by using `entity_save('cer', $cer);`

=======================

Finally figured it out. You can use the entity_import function.

1. Create a variable containing a JSON-like string of the entity (which you can get by exporting a CER entity), something like:

   $j = '{
     "identifier" : "node:time_slot:field_ref_student*commerce_line_item:registration:field_ref_slots",
     "cer_bidirectional" : { "und" : [ { "value" : "1" } ] },
     "cer_enabled" : { "und" : [ { "value" : "1" } ] },
     "cer_weight" : { "und" : [ { "value" : "0" } ] },
     "cer_left" : { "und" : [ { "path" : "node:time_slot:field_ref_student" } ] },
     "cer_right" : { "und" : [ { "path" : "commerce_line_item:registration:field_ref_slots" } ] },
     "rdf_mapping" : []
   }';
2. Then import and save:

   $e = entity_import('cer', $j);
   entity_save('cer', $e);

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for anybody looking for a way to do this argiepano's answer is not very clear. Found that their first solution works just fine, and actually that's how it's done by the code that does the importing in the CER admin UI:

```
// Create the entity using the JSON string.
$entity = entity_import('cer', '{JSON STRING HERE}');
// Now do the actual saving.
entity_save('cer', $entity);
```